# pygame Text Adventure

Tags: python, pygame

Пишу Text Adventure игру, есть начальное окно, музыка, задний фон. Проблема в том, что я хотелось бы при нажатии на кнопку старт, убрались бы кнопки и был бы черный экран, где я мог бы что то написать. У меня в результате получается...
[image: Результат]. Ну и в будущем так сказать "переключать" экраны. Заранее спасибо.

```
import pygame, sys


pygame.init()

#############
pygame.mixer.music.load('Invincible.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()

#############

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

red = (200,0,0)
green = (0,200,0)

bright_red = (255,0,0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)

block_color = (53,115,255)


gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('One Day After')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

gameIcon = pygame.image.load('gameicon.jpg')
pygame.display.set_icon(gameIcon)

pause = False

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def GameOver():
    ####################################
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play("smb_gameover.wav")
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    ####################################
    largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Game Over", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()



        button("Play Again",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,game_loop)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15) 

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            gameDisplay.fill(black)
            action()



    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))
    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)


def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
    sys.exit()

def unpause():
    global pause
    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
    pause = False


def paused():
    ############
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
    #############
    largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Paused", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


    while pause:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()


        button("Continue",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,unpause)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)   


def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        pilt1 = pygame.image.load('apoc2.jpg').convert()
        gameDisplay.blit(pilt1, [0,0])
        pygame.display.flip()


        button("Start",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,game_loop)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)


def game_loop():
    global pause

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
                if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    click.play()
                    action()






game_intro()
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю вам нужен переход по сценам...
Лично я делал так

```
import pygame
from pygame import *

pygame.init()

scene=0

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1080,600))

run=True
while run:
     for i in pygame.event.get():
          event=i
     if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
          run=False
     elif event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
          if scene==0:
               print("переключились на сцену 1")
               scene=1
     screen.fill((255,255,255))
     if scene==0:
          #тут рисуем все что надо отобразить в 0 сцене
          pygame.draw.rect(screen,(200,0,0),(100,100,100,100))
     elif scene==1:
          #тут рисуем все что надо отобразить в 1 сцене
          pygame.draw.circle(screen,(200,0,0),(100,100),100)

     pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```